# Homebrew php module not loading

Tags: php, homebrew

this is probably something simple but I have a problem with my local server. I set up a local server for building websites about 3 months ago and it worked fine until last evening the php will show as text instead of being executed by apache. I'm on a Mac. When I type:

```
$ apachectl -S
```

in terminal I get this error:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 173 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.32_8/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.32_8/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so, 10): image not found
```

I have not been able to find a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try reinstalling PHP. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php

Comment: Thanks, but no luck with that.